# conditional comment in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, conditional-comments

Consider the following, no space before [ and cannot see it as comment in ie 8 F12 console, but the overwrite style cannot be shown.

Don't use compatibility mode in new IEs, it works fine in that way, but not in the real IE 8.
What is the problem?

```
#SectionManagerContent{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    </style>
    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <style>
    #SectionManagerContent{
        height: 400px !important;
        overflow:scroll !important;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: What is the tagName of #SectionManagerContent?

section?

add modernizr.js and html5.js to your page..it will automatically add createElement('section') to your page for HTML5 semantic element support in IE8 and lower.

Comment: @RobParsons It's not html5 just a div tag